# Why no $.connection object defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

This is my HTML beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Some title</title>
</head>
```

I tried adding just before `</head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

But it doesn't help.

I also tried to remove everything besides `jQuery` and `signalR` scripts.

#### Please note: All scripts, including `jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js` (and `hubs`, if I add it) are loaded successfully (I can single step it with Chrome "Developer Tools").

So why I don't have `$.connection` object defined ?

### Edit:

I cleaned all unnecessary code, and found out meanwhile that:

1. `$.connection` does exist when I'm in `MyScript.js`, but I tried to test it first using the chrome console. In the console it does not exist... I don't understand why.
2. I save `$.connection` for the moment, in order to test it, in `someGlobalObj`:

   ```
   someGlobalObj = $.connection;
   ```

   and that works...

So my updated question would be: how-come `$.connection` is visible during my script, but invisible in the chrome console (`$`, or `jQuery` are globals) ?

Comment: What script is supposed to be adding the connection method to jQuery? Is there any documentation on that that we can see?

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery mobile twice?

Comment: what a mess! why didnt you store all js files together?

Comment: @Bergi i only see jQuery Mobile js included once.

Comment: @KevinB: Uh, right, that was a stylesheet :-|

Comment: @KevinB - I saw that link. I followed it as you can see. I believe `jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js` adds the `connection` to `jQuery`

Comment: @Tal I was posting it more for everyone else to reference

Comment: You have jQuery included twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how-come $.connection is visible during my script, but invisible in the chrome console ($, or jQuery are globals)?

There are only two explanations: Something that executes after your script (a timeout, some other script)…

- …deletes the `connection` property of the jQuery object
- …overwrites the global `$` (and even `jQuery`?) variables with similiar object(s) which don't have the `connection` property.

The second one could be the case if you also use other libraries (like Prototype).